# can't install realm with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I did pod init and wrote RealmSwift in Podfile.

I'm using 
Swift5, Xcode 11.3.1, cocoaPod 1.9.1, ruby 2.3.0

```
 # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '13.0'

 target 'project' do
   # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
   use_frameworks!

   # Pods for project
   pod 'RealmSwift'

   target 'projectTests' do
     inherit! :search_paths
     # Pods for testing
   end

   target 'projectUITests' do
     # Pods for testing
   end

end
```

I got JSON parserError like this

```
JSON::ParserError - A JSON text must at least contain two octets!
```

What should I do to fix the ParseError?
And I could install SwiftDate. I can't install only RealmSwift.

Answer (score 0):

follow these

- rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"
- rm -rf "pwd/Pods/"
- pod update

Please backup the respective directories before running "rm" commands

If not work, delete Podfile.lock and run rm commands then run pod init and  pod install

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did "rm" but doesn't work. By the way, there is no Podfile.lock. Is this weird?

Comment: @Ken i'm facing the exact same issue! no Podfile.lock and can't install Realm.